# GCP deployment manager same resource name in different deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

To figure out how deployment manager behaves when we have same resource name in different deployment I did following steps:

1. I create a deployment named dep-1 with single VM named vm1.
2. Then I created a a deployment named dep-2 with same VM named vm1.

I was thinking that dep-2 will fail saying a resource already exist with same name but it succeeded without any warning/error.

Later when I deleted dep-2 it deleted the vm resource named vm-1.

Now I want to know how to deal with this behavior. Say I want to deploy my environment for dev, qa and prod. What is the best practice to do it in GCP deployment manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you used the same yaml file for both deployments (same instance name and same zone).

- The first deployment created the instance, as expected without issues.
- The second deployment didn't create another instance, just assign the same instance to this deployment. This is why you see the instance deleted when removing the deployment dep-2.

To see the errors you can go to [Stackdriver Logging page](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs?_ga=2.265490252.-238326636.1523345235) for you project. and filter the log for [instances creation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#getting_started_with_advanced_filters).

Comment: Yes I used the same yaml file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This link documents the deployment manager update policy. The above mentioned behavior in question is expected.

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#prepare_your_update

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments#optional_determine_the_policies_to_use_for_the_update

**(Optional) Determine the policies to use for the update**

- The default policy for adding resources is CREATE_OR_ACQUIRE.
- The default policy for removing resources is DELETE.
- The default policy for updating resources is UPDATE.